# NSMutableArray in NSMutableArray as a single object

Tags: ios, xcode, nsmutablearray

I am trying to add NSMutableArray in another NSMutableArray. But what I am trying to do is nested arrays.

My current code is:

```
  NSMutableArray *array1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"Red", @"Green", @"Blue", @"Yellow", nil];
  NSMutableArray *array2 =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  [array2 addObject:array1];
```

This code is adding 4 objects in array2 but I want it to add array1 as single object.

Edit: This code is working I know but in my case in XCode something is wrong with initializing and it is adding 4 objects. I still could not figure it out. So this piece of code is working properly. So the problem was about initialization in a for loop.

Comment: You might need to use `NSDictionary` for what you are expecting. When you assign array to an array, the result will be the same.

Comment: are you sure its adding 4 objects in array2 ? as the code working fine for me, try logging count of array2.

Comment: Your code is correct.

Comment: nothing wrong with your code if you want to add array1 as single object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I copy/pasted your code, and it adds one object to array2, not four.

```
Printing description of array2:
<__NSArrayM 0xc46c7b0>(  <-- THIS ARRAY HAS 1 OBJECT
    <__NSArrayM 0xc488770>( <-- THIS ARRAY HAS 4 OBJECTS
        Red,
        Green,
        Blue,
        Yellow
    )
)
```

You may be are getting confused by the fact that printing the description, prints the contents of the inner array also.

Comment: The problem was about initialization in a for loop.I have edited the question description also. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
NSMutableArray *array2 =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:array1];
```

Comment: is this working with adding many arrays? I mean I will add array3,array4,array5 ... to array2.

Comment: Yes it does.
Try:
    [array2 addObject: array3];
    [array2 addObject: array4];

Comment: This is not different at all from the original question. It is incorrect

Comment: this answer will confuse other people in the future. The reason it works is not the change he suggested.

Comment: yes you are right but in my code something is wrong it is adding 4 objects and still couldnt find the reason.

Comment: Start a new project and copy paste this code. Tell me if that persists

Comment: yes it works in new project. I think it was some initialization problem in my previous project.

Comment: So - should I just remove my answer? I was trying to help not to cause confusion. Yet how is it incorrect? Doesn't it do what it's supposed to?

Comment: Your answer is completely equivalent to the Original Poster's code. So , if anybody reads your accepted answer will believe that your suggestion makes a difference.

Comment: And I do not blame you. I am just suggesting something. Of course you wanted to help :)

Comment: Marvellous - I was beginning to think my answer was incorrect, yet it's been more of a slightly altered rephrasing of the question itself. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Exactly, thus it is not an answer

Answer (score 0):

i am using this and its working

```
NSArray *array1 = @[array2, array3, ...];
```